# Select each foreach loop iteration based on iteration key value

Tags: php, arrays, loops, sorting

I've got the following array output:

```
array (size=102)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'MapId' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'Id'    => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'MapId' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'Id'    => string '2' (length=1)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'MapId' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'Id'    => string '3' (length=1)
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)
      public 'MapId' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'Id'    => string '4' (length=1)
```

Now what I'd like to do is get all array iterations that have a `MapId` of `1`, then all iterations that have a `MapId` of `2`, and so on.

I'm not really sure if I should create a function for `array_map()`, use a `while` loop within the `foreach` loop, or if PHP has a simple native function that can do such a thing.

Could someone shed some light on how this would be possible?

Comment: First `sort` and then do `foreach` or whatever?

Comment: `array_filter($array. function($i) use($id) { retrurn $i->MapId == $id; });`